# I have been trying to share the tfstate file between 2 different pipelines

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I have been trying to share the tfstate file between 2 different pipelines. I need to deploy infra with terraform from a different pipeline and application using terraform from different pipeline but with same tfstate file

I am able to use different tfstate files and deploy infra with one pipeline and application with another pipeline. Is there a way we can do it using a single tfstate file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at the terraform [backend state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/backends.html) management which is designed for exactly the same scenario you're describing - contributing using a shared state file. Here's how it looks like for the [Azure Provider backend state configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/azurerm.html) using a Storage Account:

```yaml
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "StorageAccount-ResourceGroup"
    storage_account_name = "abcd1234"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "prod.terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ked Mardemootoo. But its still creating a separate tfstate file in the same storage account. Can you help me around so that it uses the existing tfstate file.

Comment: You need to create reference to the same state file whenever you're calling your pipelines. You will need to ensure each pipeline has a state file reference, (i.e. exactly the same block as above) in each pipeline. Each pipeline needs to be interacting with the exact same objects. Are you using the two different pipelines to create different terraform/azure objects? Or just using the infra state file and referring to it?